# Informing entity framework what changed

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

Assume I have a set of nested business objects:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    // ...
    public AddressType Type { get; set; }
}

public enum AddressType
{
    Billing,
    Mailing
}
```

Now lets say I only want to update the customer's name. The problem I ran into is I still have to provide all the data for nested objects, even if the service method I'm calling is ignoring them.

The problem is the enums, IDs, and other values are not nullable. So EF complains that the data is null.

To make this work, I had to add dummy data to my objects (which again will just be ignored by the service method). It seems unnecessary to have to send a full object back and forth when I may only be needing a subset of data.

Is there a better way to handle partial updates with EF/WCF?

**EDIT:**

Assume the WCF service has the method:

```
public void UpdateCustomer (Customer customer)
```

I'd like to pass the service a `Customer` which is mostly empty, containing ONLY the value that changed `Name` plus the `ID`

Comment: Do you ever need this to work with a client that's not running .NET?

Comment: Is your problem with telling EF that only the `Name` changed, or are you calling an operation that only looks at the `Name`, or both?

Comment: All clients would be .NET.

Comment: I'd like the ability to tell EF that `Name` changed, and anything that's not marked/flagged as Changed should be ignored even if not nullable.

Comment: How do you plan on differentiating between a field that is to be reset , ie the fields was cleared and is now empty/default value and field that should be ignored because it is default value?   eg Address line 2 is now empty string after an edit

Answer (score 1):

There a few different patterns out there for use in Delta interfaces.
Example:  A second parameter in the interface.
The second parameter could be a MemberName Collection.
The collection is set with the name of all members caller would like processed.

Option 2, Use a different model for the interface as the actual EF class.
Marking all fields except the key optional.  You Can send XML that contained only the relevant fields. You need to check which elements where present and which not to tell the difference between 
     
and the Tag not being present.

Since  should/might mean reset to default value and a missing tag might meaning do nothing.
There are other patterns , this is just 2 examples.